# Generate new data in Variational Autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to generate new data using this [dataset](https://github.com/Mereep/keel_csv/blob/master/standard_classification/onehot/poker.prepared.csv). I have trained the VAE with a latent dimension of 10 and now I wanted to generate new samples (2000 or so, the number doesn't matter). However, when I try to predict the data I get: `Input to reshape is a tensor with 511488 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 2048 [[{{node decoder/flatten_3/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_686099]`. I have also tried with 2048 and nothing. The prediction only works if I leave the original 10 value of the latent dimension. What should I do?

Data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('local path')
class_0 = df.loc[df['Class'].isin([0])]
class_0.to_csv("local path")
data, data_test = train_test_split(class_0, test_size=0.20)
data = np.asarray(data).astype(np.float32)
data = tf.expand_dims(data, axis=-1)
latent_dim = 10
leaky_relu = tf.nn.leaky_relu
data.shape # TensorShape([410960, 10, 1])
```

Encoder:

```
encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(data.shape[1], 1), name='encoder_inputs')
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation=leaky_relu)(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(128, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation=leaky_relu)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
encoder.summary()
```

Decoder:

```
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim, 1))
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation=leaky_relu)(latent_inputs)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(256, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Dense(data.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(x)
x = Reshape((data.shape[1], 1))(x)
decoder_outputs = 
layers.Dense(data.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, x, name='decoder')
```

decoder.summary()

Training:

```
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='kl_loss', mode='min', min_delta=0.005, patience=20, verbose=0, restore_best_weights=True)

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)



vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0000002))
hist = vae.fit(data, epochs=50, batch_size=128, callbacks=[earlystopper])
```

Generate new data:

```
new_data = vae.decoder.predict(np.random.normal(0,1,size=(1, 2000, 1))) #This is where I get the error
```

Comment: What is the input shape to your encoder?

Comment: I have added the encoder to the question, however, the shape is [(None, 10, 1)] @AloneTogether

Comment: where 10 is data.shape[1]

Comment: But then you cannot use (2000, 1) if the input shape is (10, 1), or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I see that. I have taken part of the code from keras tutorial, is like the input shape is fixed. So there is no way for me to generate large amounts of new data with that VAE design? @AloneTogether

Comment: Can you define what you mean with "large"? You can always increase the number of samples `np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2000, 10, 1)))` <-- 2000 samples.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was being an ignorant, I didn't know the first argument of the predictor was the number of samples, thanks! @AloneTogether